# How to scroll into view each item in a node list one after another in one line of code on keypress?

Tags: javascript

I have a page that I'd like to scroll each element into view in one line of code.

Code I have so far:

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) { e.keyCode==13 ?document.querySelectorAll("ins").scrollIntoView():void})
```

I thought I could get it to work with a single element but I'm not getting key events (nevermind it's no script on local file):

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) { console.log("test") })
```

Comment: why is one line of code important ?

Comment: @jonathanHeindl There are a few reasons and constraints. It could be a few lines. The main reason is to prevent errors if that makes sense.

Comment: var current=0;function scrollIntoView(index){document.querySelectorAll("ins")[index].scrollIntoView()}window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) { e.keyCode==13 ? scrollIntoView(current++) :void })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var current=0;
function scrollIntoView(index){
    let node=document.querySelectorAll("ins")[index];
    if(node){
         node.scrollIntoView();
     }
}
window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) { 
      e.keyCode==13 ? scrollIntoView(current++) :void
});
```

ot in one line :

```
var current=0;function scrollIntoView(index){let node=document.querySelectorAll("ins")[index];if(node){node.scrollIntoView();         }}window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) { e.keyCode==13 ? scrollIntoView(current++) :void })
```

```js
var current=0;

function scrollIntoView(index){
   let node=document.querySelectorAll("ins")[index];
   if(node){
       node.scrollIntoView();
   }
};

window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
   current>=document.querySelectorAll("ins").length ? current = 0 : null;
   e.keyCode==13 && document.querySelectorAll("ins").length && scrollIntoView(current++);
});
```

```html
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br>
<br>
<ins>first index</ins><br>
<br><br>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.<br><br><br>
<ins>second index</ins><br><br><br>
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br><br><br>
<ins>third index</ins><br><br><br>
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.<br><br><br>

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.<br><br><br>

There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.
```

Comment: ah nice I didnt put the comparison on if its too high :o